# How to add an image file to an object and push that object into an array with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, image, object, javascript-objects

I want to load an image into an object, and then push that object to an existing array containing other objects with their own strings, which I hard coded in JavaScript.

I successfully created a form to input values for the object and it worked, the string values(name, phone number) have been successfully pushed into the already existing array, but the image is not there.

My JavaScript code :

```js
let thatArray = [{
    name: "webster",
    phone: "0771364325",
    img: "./person-1.jpeg"
}, {
    name: "ndhlove",
    phone: "077112233",
    img: "./zindunalogo.png"
}, {
    name: "webbyy",
    phone: "051561561545",
    img: "./oooo (2).jpg"
}];

const form = document.getElementById('contact-form');

form.addEventListener('submit', formFun);

function formFun(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const myFormData = new FormData(event.target);

    const formDataObj = {};
    myFormData.forEach((value, key) => (formDataObj[key] = value));

    document.getElementById("imageUpload").addEventListener("change", function(e) {
        let newImg = new Image('350', '480');
        newImg.src = e.target.files[0];
        newImg.src = URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]);
        formDataObj.appendChild(newImg);
    });

    thatArray.push(formDataObj);
    console.log(thatArray);

    const newJsonArray = JSON.stringify(thatArray);

    localStorage.setItem('array', newJsonArray);
};
```

And HTML:

```html
<body>
   <form id="contact-form">
      <div class="form-control">
         <label for="name">Full Name</label>
         <input id="name" name="name" type="text" />
      </div>
      <div class="form-control">
         <label for="phone">Phone number</label>
         <input id="phone" name="phone" type="number" />
      </div>
      <div class="form-control">
         <label for="image">Upload Image</label>
         <input type="file" id="imageUpload">
      </div>
      <button type="submit">submit</button>
   </form>
   <button class="addBtn">ADD</button>
   <div class="displayImagePreview">
      <img id="preview-selected-image" />
   </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Why are you only adding the change handler for the field input field, _inside_ of your form submit handler? The selection in the input field is not going to change any more, _after_ you already triggered the form submission. These should either be _independent_ event handlers, or you just read the current file selection of the field inside the submit handler directly.

Comment: I now added the event listener before the submit button, and now it works. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Nothing happen on the array because you add EventListener of the input file after the submit button is clicked. You need to add the event listener before the submit button is clicked

```js
const form = document.getElementById('contact-form');

    form.addEventListener('submit', formFun);
    const formDataObj = {};
    document.getElementById("imageUpload").addEventListener("change", function(e) {
            console.log(`Changed`);
        let newImg = new Image('350', '480');
        newImg.src = e.target.files[0];
        newImg.src = URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]);
        formDataObj.img = (newImg);
        });
    function formFun(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        const myFormData = new FormData(event.target);
       
        myFormData.forEach((value, key) => {
            formDataObj[key] = value
        });
        thatArray.push(formDataObj);
        console.log(thatArray);
            
        const newJsonArray = JSON.stringify(thatArray);

        localStorage.setItem('array', newJsonArray);
        };
```

Comment: thank you @Salah a. I also realize i had usedthe 'formDataObj' variable as a function. thanks for the correction!